# Complete this proof of Abel's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

Prove Abel's theorem: If $\sum a^n$ converges, then $\lim_{r_{<1} \to 1} \sum r^na^n = \sum a^n$.  (All sums here are from $n = 1$ to $n = \infty$ unless otherwise noted.)

***Note:** Proof's of Abel's theorem are readily available on [this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225543/proof-abels-formula?rq=1) and [elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).  My goal is to help me complete* my *proof*.

---

Proof attempt:

For constant $ 0 < r < 1$, by summation by parts,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N r^n a^n = r^N \sum_{n=1}^N a^n - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(r^{n+1} - r^n)a^n \\
$$
I am *assuming* that, for the limit case of $N = \infty$, the analog is true:
$$
\sum r^n a^n = \lim_{N \to \infty} r^N \sum_{n=1}^N a^n - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(r^{n+1} - r^n)a^n \\
$$
and also assuming that the analog remains true for $\lim r_{<1} \to 1$:
$$
\lim r \to 1 \sum r^n a^n = \lim r \to 1 \lim_{N \to \infty} r^N \sum_{n=1}^N a^n - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(r^{n+1} - r^n)a^n \\
$$

It would seem to me that both of those analogs need to be proven.  Is that correct? How?

Next, it seems to be that $\lim r \to 1 \lim_{N \to \infty} r^N = 0$, although I don't know how to make that rigorous.  Normally, you'd apply L'Hopital's rule to the indeterminate form $1^\infty$, which compares the rate of growth.  But here what's growing is the *limit*, not a function: How do you assess the rate of growth of a variable approaching a limit?

That leaves:
$$
\lim r \to 1 \sum r^n a^n = \sum (r^n - r^{n+1})a^n \\
$$
which I surmise could be shown to simply equal $\sum a^n$; again, I'm not sure how.

Comment: I'd think "proof-explanation" was for a proof you saw in the literature for which you wanted some steps explained. This looks like you have tried to construct your own proof but need assistance to finish it. [I'm just wondering about your choice of "proof-expnanation" label.]

Comment: @coffemath "proof-explanation" was the most appropriate tag I could find.  I wasn't able to find "proof-assistance" or a better synonym than "explanation".  If there is one, please direct me to it.  Regardless, can you help me with my proof?

Comment: SRobert-- sorry I don't know how to finish. There is a label for "proof verification" But I guess that would only apply if you had already obtained a complete proof and wanted someone to check the steps.

Comment: $\lim_r \lim_N r^N $ need not necessarily be equal to $\lim_N \lim_r r^N  = 1^{\infty}$. You can only change the order of limits had  the limit $\lim_{r \to 1, N \to \infty} r^N$ existed. So $\lim_r \lim_N r^N =  \lim_r 0 = 0.$